# Model Release forms

Tags: contract-law, california, binding

I found a model release form:

https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1LkkT_XwXwnnzwOxtGAirvVvVXzbU2YVUQeZ0kiqbGmQ

I was wondering how binding this form is, and how necessary including the address is.

Comment: I believe the address is only there because professional photographers would encounter models with the same name more often than you would think. Being able to produce the correct document when needed would considered very necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all contracts, ***how*** binding depends on ***all the facts and circumstances*** relevant to any challenges to it's validity. Generally speaking, though, all written contracts are binding ***prima facie*** (on their face) provided all parties are of legal age and the contract itself does not prescribe any illegal act. (There are also other requirements not germane to the question.)

There is no requirement for an address to be included in a contract in order for it to be binding.

I am not an attorney. I am not your attorney. So please do not act on anything I or anyone else writes in this forum. Please consult an attorney if you need legal advice.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed some face value info, thanks for your time!